# Android - Can not open launcher chooser (to let user choose default launcher)

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, android-launcher

I'm working on my own launcher. By default, onResume() : my launcher checks if it's the default launcher or not. If not, it will open a launcher selector. Howerver, it doesn't work properly.

- If the phone doesn't have any default launcher, I can open the selector >> **OK**.
- If there is a default launcher (always type), my launcher app quits to home page (of the current default launcher) >> **FAIL** (my launcher still run underground and no exception was found).

My phone is Android 4.4.2. Can you help me pls? Thanks you.

The code:

```
public void resetPreferredLauncherAndOpenChooser() {
    final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();

    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, MainActivity.class);
    packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

    Intent selector = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    selector.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);

    try {
        startActivity(selector);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
    }

    packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DEFAULT, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
```

Comment: So you are trying to force the user to select a launcher app each time even when the user has already set a different launcher as default?

Comment: Since user open my launcher app, I want to force user set it to the default launcher. Can it?

Comment: I do the check on onResume() event

Comment: It's best to send the user to the settings screen instead like in [this tutorial](http://weimenglee.blogspot.in/2013/06/android-tip-programmatically-displaying.html). Use [ACTION_HOME_SETTINGS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_HOME_SETTINGS) instead.

Comment: @miva2 , thanks, this works nice